# Get date time in correct format from SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column `ifd0_DateTime` , in a table named `photo`, which contains date time in following format: `1966:12:22 17:19:57`. 
I need to count the number of photos month wise for every year.

So far I have this query. but it doesn't work correctly.

`SELECT ifd0_DateTime, count(*) FROM photo
group by YEAR(ifd0_DateTime), MONTH(ifd0_DateTime);`

Could anyone please fix this ?

Comment: How does your query not work?

Comment: I fixed it later.

Comment: Why downvotes ? Should I remove this question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(ifd0_DateTime, 7), '%Y:%m'),
       COUNT(*) AS dateCnt
FROM photo
GROUP BY STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(ifd0_DateTime, 7), '%Y:%m')
```

Comment: Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'STR_TO_DATE'

Comment: @piyush121 There was a comma missing.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `date` select the `Year` and `Month`

Try this

```
SELECT YEAR(ifd0_DateTime), MONTH(ifd0_DateTime), count(*) 
FROM photo
group by YEAR(ifd0_DateTime), MONTH(ifd0_DateTime)
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to store a date time is using the built-in data types.  However, it looks like you are storing the value as a string.  If so, you just want the first 7 characters:

```
SELECT LEFT(ifd0_DateTime, 7) as yyyymm, count(*)
FROM photo
GROUP BY LEFT(ifd0_DateTime, 7)
ORDER BY yyyymm;
```

However, you really should fix the data.

Comment: I may be wrong. I thought you were asking that if its a valid datetime. But your  query gave vague result.